# wcf why can't I see my https site

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl

I have created a simple webservice.
Then i created an Console Host which must host the service via a https url..

This is my config:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <services>
            <service behaviorConfiguration="mexBehaviour" name="NuriServiceLibrary.NuriService">
                <clear />
                <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHttpBindingConfig"
                    contract="NuriServiceLibrary.iNuriService" listenUriMode="Explicit" />
                <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpsBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
                <host>
                    <baseAddresses>
                        <add baseAddress="https://192.168.....:8001/SecureConsole" />
                    </baseAddresses>
                </host>
            </service>
        </services>
      <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
          <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
            <serviceMetadata  httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"  />
          </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
      </behaviors>

      <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="basicHttpBindingConfig">
            <security mode="Transport">
              <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
            </security>
          </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
      </bindings>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

and this is my program.cs:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(NuriService));
            host.Open();
            foreach (Uri address in host.BaseAddresses)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Listening on " + address);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Press <Enter> to terminate Host.\n\n");
            Console.ReadLine();

            host.Close();
        }
```

I have created a certificate by :
1. makecert.exe -sr LocalMachine -ss My -n CN=192.168..... -sky exchange -sk -pe
2. netsh http add sslcert ipport=192.168....:8001 certhash=(intentionally left) appid={(intentionally left)}

But the problem is, i Can't see my https webpage... I see this website is not available..
Anyone got an idea?

Comment: What URL are you using to access the service metadata?

Comment: none, i added the ip with port :9000 but then website wouldnt also show..

Comment: Where have you "*added*" the IP address with port 9000? Also, when you say "*website*", do you mean the WCF help page?

Comment: No if i press F5 then my console starts... Then if i open the https link i won't see my wcf page but nothing only page doesnt exist..

Comment: What URL does the *HTTPS link* point to?

Comment: it seems like it won't host that url or something:S

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the [HttpsGetUrl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.servicemetadatabehavior.httpsgeturl.aspx) attribute to the `<serviceMetadata>` and specify an *empty string*:

```
<serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mexBehaviour">
        <serviceMetadata  httpGetEnabled="false"
                          httpsGetEnabled="true"
                          httpsGetUrl="" />
    </behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
```

This will make the service metadata available through the service's [base address](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms788995.aspx):

```
https://localhost:8001/SecureConsole?wsdl
```

Comment: What do you get if you try to access the URL with Internet Explorer?

Comment: Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage

Comment: Try *disabling* HTTPS and see if you can access the service through `http://localhost:8001/SecureConsole?wsdl`.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/DxjGYEUS this i got now and it says Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]. for ServiceHost host = new ServiceHost(typeof(NuriService));

Comment: Change line `30` to `<security mode="None">`

Comment: then it works, i got this now http://pastebin.com/yY84fU8D, but how to configure the ssl?

Comment: I got it working i changed the ip to localhost and added netsh with this ip 0.0.0.0:8001

Comment: but if i change the base address from localhost to my computers ip address, then i can only connect to the HTTP but not the HTTPS,, i need to fill in the ip address because i want that other computers on the lan can access the httpS url

Comment: http://my.opera.com/cotzo87/blog/wcf-https-self-hosted-service-certificate-installation-guide this helped :) thnx

Answer (score 0):

By your implementation you can only expect to see the meta data published by your service by addressing your base address in a web browser. BEFORE you try and do this it is worthwhile to run your service in the debugegr in visual studios (do not run the host, just run the service/ lib). If this runs without error THEN try and address the service in the browser.

If what you really want is to host your service and and use a web browser as a client then you need to look into ASP.net